# exception :Hibernate No configuration found

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, orm, ehcache

Application is trying to load `ehcache.xml` but could not find the file so then it loads `ehcache-failsafe.xml`. I would like to know does this cause any problem to application?

```
No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from `ehcache-failsafe.xml`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must create hibernate.cfg.xml file for configuration. This file get parameters for database connection and etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this warning, you need to add your own `ehcache.xml` configuration file in the root of your classpath.

If you are using Maven that would go into:

```
${project_path}/src/main/resources/ehcache.xml
```

You need this configuration file because you certainly have specific requirements for each cache region (e.g. expiry time, overflow to disk, max entries).